# What is the point of static {} inside a Groovy class?

Tags: groovy

What effect does `static {}` have?

There is one such code block in [SimpleXlsSlurper](https://github.com/yellowsnow/GroovyUtils/blob/master/xls/SimpleXlsSlurper.groovy) for example.

Comment: +1 because I have no friggen idea. I would have mistaken it for a messup, but maybe it's something sweet.

Comment: I don't have a "for certain" answer, but I believe it's just an empty statement - in Java, you would use [a static block](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) to initialize static variables.  But if the block is empty, it probably just get's compiled away.

Comment: Usually I'd say that there probably used to be some code in there, but looking at the history the empty static initializer was already there in the first version.

Answer (score 6):

There is no point in having an empty static initializer, neither in Java nor in Groovy.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprized if the empty static initializer block triggered something behind the scenes in certain coding scenarios due to bugs in Groovy.